# How to give an access to the internet to another PC via Ethernet (Windows 7)?

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, router

I have one Desktop PC which is connected to internet through WiFi (WiFi adapter) and another PC that should be connected to the internet to via first one.

I plugged Ethernet cable between two PCs, but doesn't work. I am using Windows 7 in both PCs.

How to connect these two computers so that they both have internet and LAN to share docs between each other and other PCs those connected to WiFi router?

Answer (score 3):

You might try to change the tcp/ip configuration manually.

**On the PC with wireless**

- right click on the Network icon
- click on Network center
- click on Adapter options
- right click on LAN-adapter
- click on "Bridge connection"
- wait to see active a new bridge icon
- right click on the bridge-adapter
- choose tcp/ip options
- in the IP field assign an IP e.g. 192.168.1.101
- in the Subnet field assign e.g. 255.255.255.0 or the same as for wlan-  network
- in the gateway field assign the IP form your WLAN modem (see WLAN-adapter-status-details or ipv4 options)
- in the DNS 1 field assign the gateway-IP
- click ok
- disable bridge adapter and reenable it after few seconds

**On the PC without wireless**

- right click on the Network icon
- click on Network center
- click on Adapter options
- right click on LAN-adapter
- click on options
- choose tcp/ip options
- in the IP field assign an IP e.g. 192.168.1.102
- in the Subnet field assign e.g. 255.255.255.0 or the same as for wlan-  network
- in the gateway field assign the IP form your WLAN modem (see WLAN-adapter-status-details or ipv4 options)
- in the DNS 1 field assign the gateway-IP
- click ok

**If this don't work**

- In the tcp/ip options choose the "share" tab
- enable "allow other computers in the network to use internet"
- click ok

Comment: Depending on nics, you may also need a cross-over cable. Most have mdi-x these days though.

Comment: I have tried this already, but it doesn't work

Comment: You need to bridge it, see the edit.