# How to cascad Mobile Broadband internet to another PC?

Tags: networking, windows-10, switch, connection-sharing

A Windows 10 PC is connected to the internet through a mobile USB tethering (connection works). Another PC, running Windows Server, is connected to the first PC via a network switch.

Please, **how to make the internet connection, propagate** into the second PC ?

Already read a dozen Q/A, but none worked for me. This [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1310064/701651) *about sharing a* *WiFi connection*, seems to be a good beginning, but didn't work.

---

In detail:

1. in the first PC, assigned to the wired connection a static IP `192.168.42.10`. In the second, `192.168.42.5`. Pinging works.
2. Bridged the RNDIS connection and the wired one. This created a bridge connection, but broken the internet connectivity for the first PC.
3. Removed the RNDIS from the bridge.
   [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution worked for the poster:

After
[creating the network bridge](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/create-a-network-bridge-windows)
between the tethered phone and the LAN, the next step is to enable
[Internet Connection Sharing (ICS)](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2455390&seqNum=6).

This is done in the network adapter, right-click and selecting Properties,
in the Sharing tab.

This allowed to share the Internet access from the tethered mobile with the rest of
the network.